# Abstract Algebra+group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is asserted that a group G of order 5, G={e,a,b,c,d }, has the following Cayley table
[image: Cayley table]

The question says:Is the assertion correct?

Comment: A group of order $5$ is cyclic.  Does this table describe a cyclic group?

Answer (score 3):

A group with 5 elements must necessarily be cyclic and must be generated by every element except the identity (prove this!) But $b*b = e$ and hence cannot generate the group.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comment below the post, every group of order $5$ is cyclic. (Indeed, any group of prime order is cyclic.) Every cyclic group is abelian. (The group operation is commutative.)

Does the Cayley Table depict an abelian group? Are the entries ALL symmetric about the diagonal?

If not, $G$ cannot be a group.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* & e & a & b & c & d \\
\hline
e & e & a & b & c & d \\
a & a & c & d & e & b \\
b & b & d & e & a & c \\
c & c & b & a & d & e \\
d & d & e & c & b & a \\
\end{array}$$

Here's three more ways to show that this is not the Cayley table of a group:

- We see that $$(a*a)*b=c*b=a$$ and $$a*(a*b)=a*d=b \neq a$$ and therefore $*$ is not an associative binary operation.
- We see that $e$ must be the identity element, and we also see that $a*c=e$, which, if $(\{a,b,c,d,e\},*)$ were a group, would imply $c=a^{-1}$, and thus $c*a=e$, but we instead see $c*a=b$.
- [Lagrange's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) implies the order of an element divides the order of a group.  The element $b$ has order $2$, which does not divide $5$.